# Merge [averah] with [sin]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Someone created [averah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/averah) (2 questions), but there's an existing tag, [sin](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin), with 165 question. Can someone synonymize [averah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/averah) with [sin](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sin)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've now effected this merger.